# Unable to shut down in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, shutdown

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 dual boot alongside windows 11. Everything was working fine except i cant power off or suspend my laptop in ubuntu. The computer screen turn black but the fan, keyboard light keep going.
So is there anyone know what the problem and how to fix it?